# What is (S’73-M’76-SM’81-F’87) in author biography?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, ieee

What does (S’73-M’76-SM’81-F’87) mean in author biography. I am writing a paper and the format given for author biography also include a must fill entry: (S’73-M’76-SM’81-F’87). I tried to Google it and I can see many similar entries in authors biographies in published papers.

Can someone please help me about how to fill up the field (S’73-M’76-SM’81-F’87) for myself?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I base my answer on my familiarity with the IEEE. Other societies may follow similar conventions.*

For members of the IEEE, the notation in your example is a "shorthand" way for indicating when the author achieved a certain membership status within the society. For example,

> (S’73-M’76-SM’81-F’87)

means that A. N. Author became a *Student Member* (S) in 1973, a *Member* (M) in 1976, a *Senior Member* (SM) in 1981, and an *IEEE Fellow* (F) in 1987.

If you are not a member of the IEEE, then you do not use this shorthand in your biography.

Answer (score 7):

*As well as [Mad Jack](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/11192/mad-jack), I'm basing my answer on IEEE.*

You can find IEEE's documents guiding authors on how to style their papers. The most updated one that I could find today can be download from [here](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/your-role-in-article-production/ieee-editorial-style-manual/). The document is called [IEEE Editorial Style Manual](http://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Editorial-Style-Manual.pdf) and it was published in 07/10/19.

The passage you are looking for is located in the **section Biographies**, **page 13**:

> [...] The format for listing the IEEE membership history is to list each grade of membership attained followed by an apostrophe and the year it was attained, with each year and grade combination separated from the others by an en dash. Note that if an author attains the same membership grade in more than one year, list only the first year that it was reached. The current membership listed with the biography must match the byline.
>
> Abbreviations for IEEE membership grades are S (Student Member), GS (Graduate Student Member), A (Associate Member), M (Member), SM (Senior Member), F (Fellow), LA (Life Associate Member), LM (Life Member), LSM (Life Senior Member), and LF (Life Fellow). Note that A stands for Associate, not Affiliate, Member. Affiliate memberships are not listed in the byline or biography membership history. Do not include references to IEEE membership from the text of the biography.